# Некорректно отрабатывае bat скрипт, если стоит RedirectStandardOutput

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Имеется такой скрипт

```
@echo off
xcopy /R /Y "D:\test.dll" "C:\Users\testuser\Desktop"
```

Если его запустить, он корректно отрабатывает и копирует файл.
Если запустить его из этого кода, то файл почему то не копируется! Но самый интересный факт состоит в том что, если я отключаю `RedirectStandardOutput` то файл копируется. В чем проблема?

```
var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + @"D:\test.bat");
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = windir;
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);

        var process = Process.Start(processInfo);

        process.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.Data))
            {
                LogTextEvent(rtbLog, Color.Black, e.Data);
            }
        };

process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();
process.Close();
```

Comment: Значит у вас проблема с редиректом. Попробуйте другой способ редиректа. Например msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  или http://www.dotnetperls.com/redirectstandardoutput

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает.

Comment: Чтение StdOutput у вас в отдельном потоке (thread)?

Comment: Да процесс запускается в отдельном потоке

Comment: Вы не правильно понимаете. По хорошему нужно создать **pipe** чтение которого в отдельном потоке. А так как чтение и ожидание у вас в одном потоке (должно быть в двух) - у вас может возникнуть "конфликт". Попробуйте чтение stdout создать в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Вообще в этом бат файле, много разных команд и все они отрабатывают кроме копирования файлов. Вы думаете это из за того что бат файл запускается в фоновом потоке?

Comment: Ещё раз уточню. У вас должно быть три потока. Одни - основной (есть), второй - запуск батника (есть), и третий - который читает stdout возможно лучше по одному байту т.к. bat-программа может не давать `\r\n`  (нету).

Comment: Я вот щас убрал `process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` т.е. чтения нету. Файл все равно не копируется. А должен ли в этом случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается дело было в команде `xcopy`
Именно в **WinForm** - это важно! В консольном приложении работают обе команды.

Не работает:

```
xcopy /R /Y "D:\test.dll" "C:\Users\testuser\Desktop"
```

Работает:

```
copy /Y "D:\test.dll" "C:\Users\testuser\Desktop"
```

Comment: Странно, я скомпоновал cs-ку c параметром `csc.exe 1.cs /target:winexe` убрал Console.Write - и сработало.

Answer (score 1):

Я вам в ссылках прислал примеры. Они работают, вот по первой ссылке (поправите директории на свои)

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;



public class Demo {


static void Main() {
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + @"test.bat");
        processInfo.WorkingDirectory = "d:\\work\\cs";
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);

      //  var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
using (Process process = Process.Start(processInfo))
    {
        //
        // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
        //
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(result);
        }
    }

    }}
```

Результат

```
D:\work\cs>1.exe
D:1.exe
Скопировано файлов: 1.
```

этот ответ правда не самый хороший, по хорошему нужно перехватывать и Stdoutput и Stderror и Stdinput, но как часный случай - подойдёт.

Comment: Хм. Странный факт. Если ваш пример запустить в консольном приложении он отрабатывает, файл копируется. Но он же на WinForm по кнопке, файл не копируется. А вот если выключить `RedirectStandardOutput` файл копируется. Я не понимаю как это связано, ведь это всего лишь вывод а не исполнение.